# The method resetApp() is undefined for the type AppiumDriver

Tags: java, appium, appium-ios, appium-desktop, appium-java

I am using appium 8.1.1 java client, I am trying to use driver.resetApp() in my code for IOS app, but it shows as The method resetApp() is undefined for the type  AppiumDriver

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Restart the app or reset the app data? Resetting the app data has never been possible on iOS (or at least for a long, long time) - the only way to reset the app data on iOS is to re-install the app.

Comment: Basically i want to close and launch the app to the same page, is it possible?

Comment: I took a quick glance at the Java docs for 8.1.1 and for me the way to go would probably be:  
`driver.terminateApp(); driver.activateApp();`
This will close the app and re-open it - it will not bring you back to the last screen though. To just minimize and bring back you can try:
`driver.runAppInBackground​();`

Answer (score 1):

AppiumDriver methods resetApp, launchApp and closeApp have been deprecated in appium v8 as they are going to be removed from future Appium versions. Check [appium/appium#15807](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/15807) for more details.

**UPDATE:** I wrote my own resetApp() method (for Android).

```
 public void startActivity(){
    AppiumDriver driver = DRIVER.get();
    String appPackage = driver.getCapabilities().getCapability("appPackage").toString()+"/.HomeActivity";
   driver.executeScript("mobile: startActivity", ImmutableMap.of("intent", appPackage));

}

public void clearApp() {
    AppiumDriver driver = DRIVER.get();
    String appPackage = driver.getCapabilities().getCapability("appPackage").toString();
    driver.executeScript("mobile: clearApp", ImmutableMap.of("appId", appPackage));
}


public void myResetApp(){
    clearApp();
    startActivity();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason is that you have the generic appium driver that can be "anything" (android ios windows etc)

if you want the functions that are for a specific mobile driver you would probably have to cast it to that driver type.
eg

```
((IOSDriver) driver).resetApp()
```

you can still use this, however these are also deprecated methods.
I'm yet to upgrade my code as well removing these, this is the forum I saved to do it in the future:

https://applitools.com/blog/whats-new-appium-java-client-8/